# Error converting Flink DataStream to Table after a ProcessFunction call

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm implementing a data analysis pipeline in Flink and I have a problem converting a DataStream to a Table. I have this table defined from a join between two Kafka sources:

```
    Table legalFileEventsTable = legalFilesTable.join(eventsTable)
            .where($("id").isEqual($("id_fascicolo")))
            .select(
                    $("id").as("id_fascicolo"),
                    $("id_evento"),
                    $("giudice"),
                    $("nrg"),
                    $("codice_oggetto"),
                    $("ufficio"),
                    $("sezione"),
                    $("data_evento"),
                    $("evento"),
                    $("data_registrazione_evento")
            );
```

Then I convert the joined table to a DataStream to apply some computation on the data. Here's the code I'm using:

```
    DataStream<Row> phasesDurationsDataStream = tEnv.toChangelogStream(legalFileEventsTable)
            .keyBy(r -> r.<Long>getFieldAs("id_fascicolo"))
            .process(new PhaseDurationCounterProcessFunction());
    phasesDurationsDataStream.print();
```

The PhaseDurationCounterProcessFunction emits a Row like this:

```
Row outputRow = Row.withNames(RowKind.INSERT);
        outputRow.setField("id_fascicolo", currentState.getId_fascicolo());
        outputRow.setField("nrg", currentState.getNrg());
        outputRow.setField("giudice", currentState.getGiudice());
        outputRow.setField("codice_oggetto", currentState.getCodice_oggetto());
        outputRow.setField("ufficio", currentState.getUfficio());
        outputRow.setField("sezione", currentState.getSezione());
        outputRow.setField("fase", currentState.getPhase());
        outputRow.setField("fase_completata", false);
        outputRow.setField("durata", currentState.getDurationCounter());
        out.collect(outputRow);
```

After collecting the results from the process function I reconvert the DataStream to a Table and execute the pipeline:

```
    Table phasesDurationsTable = tEnv.fromChangelogStream(
            phasesDurationsDataStream,
            Schema.newBuilder()
                    .column("id_fascicolo", DataTypes.BIGINT())
                    .column("nrg", DataTypes.STRING())
                    .column("giudice", DataTypes.STRING())
                    .column("codice_oggetto", DataTypes.STRING())
                    .column("ufficio", DataTypes.STRING())
                    .column("sezione", DataTypes.STRING())
                    .column("fase", DataTypes.STRING())
                    .column("fase_completata", DataTypes.BOOLEAN())
                    .column("durata", DataTypes.BIGINT())
                    .primaryKey("id_fascicolo", "fase")
                    .build(),
            ChangelogMode.upsert()
    );
    env.execute();
```

But during the startup I receive this exception:

```
Unable to find a field named 'id_fascicolo' in the physical data type derived from the given type information for schema declaration. Make sure that the type information is not a generic raw type. Currently available fields are: [f0]
```

It seems that the row information (name and type) aren't available yet and so the exception is generated. I tried to invoke the env.execute() before the DataStream->Table conversion and in this case the job starts but I have no output if I print the phasesDurationsTable. Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the correct type information for Flink because it cannot figure out the schema from the generic `Row` type.

Here is an example, given our data stream is producing records like this:

```
Row exampleRow = Row.ofKind(RowKind.INSERT, "sensor-1", 32);
```

We need to define the correct type information the following way:

```
TypeInformation<?>[] types = {
    BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO,
    BasicTypeInfo.LONG_TYPE_INFO
};
```

Using this we can define the row type information:

```
RowTypeInfo rowTypeInfo = new RowTypeInfo(
    types,
    new String[]{"sensor_name", "temperature"}
);
```

The last step is to specify the return type of this `DataStream`:

```
DataStream<Row> stream = env.fromSource(...).returns(rowTypeInfo)
```

Note that when using `fromChangelogStream` you only need to provide a schema if you want to use a different one from the type info returned by the `DataStream`, so `tEnv.fromChangelogStream(stream)` works just fine and will use `sensor_name` and `temperature` as the schema by default.