# After applying returns(TypeInformation) to my avro generic DataStreamSource, it prints out nothing but without error

Tags: apache-flink, avro

Hi flink users/contributors,

I am posting here to see if there are any smarter ideas.

- I am using Flink to consume kafka topics in Avro Generic Records format, using a generic record deserializer and then creating a Flink Table on top of it.
- Since the data stream of Generic type, in order to avoid RAW data type (something like `f0` RAW('org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord', '...') in my table, i finally found an approach to use [returns(TypeInformation)](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/datastream/SingleOutputStreamOperator.html#returns-org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation-) to infer underlying schema, thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75418922/error-converting-flink-datastream-to-table-after-a-processfunction-call).
- The table schema based off of this data stream is exactly what i want:

```
(
  `common` ROW<`eventType` STRING, `orderNumber` STRING, `orderLineId` STRING>,
  `rowtime` TIMESTAMP_LTZ(3) *ROWTIME* METADATA,
  WATERMARK FOR `rowtime`: TIMESTAMP_LTZ(3) AS SOURCE_WATERMARK()
)
```

However, when i tried to print out the consumed data stream, it didn't output anything, no error either. I used to see output without `returns`.
Anyone knows the reason ? Thank you in advance!

Here's my code:

```
var kafkaReader =
KafkaReader.\<GenericRecord\>builder()
           .config(config)
           .topics(sourceTopic)
           .deserializationSchema(
               new ConfluentRegistryGenericAvro(
                    schema,
                    config.getSchemaRegistryOptions().registryUrl,
                    config.getSchemaRegistryOptions().toMap()))
               .build();
TypeInformation\<GenericRecord\> datatype =
AvroSchemaConverter.convertToTypeInfo(schema.toString());

var stream =
streamExecutionEnvironment
       .fromSource(
           kafkaReader.kafkaSource(),
           WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(),
           sourceTopic)
       .returns(datatype);
//print nothing
stream.printToErr();
```

1. Tried to add `returns` to the data stream for flink to infer underlying schema of a generic record stream.
2. Expect some output when i consume the topic
3. But it printed out nothing